Merge two plots with a common x-axis
Consider the code for the bifurcation diagram:
res = Internal`Bag[]; tmax = 5; {x0, y0, z0} = {1, 1, 1};

Suppose I define p1 as:
p1 = Do[sol = 
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == 10 (y[t] - x[t]), 
       y'[t] == (r*1) x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
       z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 4 z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
       z[0] == z0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
       WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {r, z[t]}]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];{x0, y0, z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;, {r, 1, 200, 0.5}];

ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All], PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "z"}, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, FrameLabel -> {"r", "Z"}]

and p2 as:
p2 = Do[sol = 
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == 9 (y[t] - x[t]), 
       y'[t] == (r*2) x[t] - y[t] - x[t] z[t], 
       z'[t] == x[t] y[t] - 5 z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
       z[0] == z0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
       WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {r, z[t]}]]}, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];{x0, y0, z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;, {r, 1, 200, 0.5}];

ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All], PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, AxesLabel -> {"r", "z"}, Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}}, FrameLabel -> {"r", "Z"}]

How can I merge p1 and p2 with a common x-axis as shown in this plot: https://i.sstatic.net/UXZnF8ED.png
Any help would be really appreciated.

Ummm... Plot[{f[x],g[x]},{x,0,1}]...?

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

res = Internal`Bag[]; tmax = 5; {x0, y0, z0} = {1, 1, 1};

p1 = Do[sol = 
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == 10  (y[t] - x[t]), 
       y'[t] == (r*1)  x[t] - y[t] - x[t]  z[t], 
       z'[t] == x[t]  y[t] - 4  z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
       z[0] == z0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
       WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {r, z[t]}]]}, {x, 
       y, z}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]; {x0, y0, 
     z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;, {r, 1, 200, 0.5}];

lp1 = ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All], 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {"r", "Z"}];

EDIT: Reset definition of res for second plot
res = Internal`Bag[];

p2 = Do[sol = 
    NDSolve[{x'[t] == 9  (y[t] - x[t]), 
       y'[t] == (r*2)  x[t] - y[t] - x[t]  z[t], 
       z'[t] == x[t]  y[t] - 5  z[t], x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, 
       z[0] == z0,(*save extrema of z[t]*)
       WhenEvent[z'[t] == 0, Internal`StuffBag[res, {r, z[t]}]]}, {x, 
       y, z}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]; {x0, y0, 
     z0} = {x[tmax], y[tmax], z[tmax]} /. sol;, {r, 1, 200, 0.5}];

lp2 = ListPlot[Internal`BagPart[res, All], 
   PlotStyle -> {Gray, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]}, Frame -> True,
    FrameLabel -> {"r", "Z"}];

With version 12 or later use ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{{lp1}, {lp2}}]



There are two bifurcation diagrams on the bottom-plot. That seems to be an error

They' re  your  plots . I  merely  showed  you  how  to  stack  them. Presumably, you want to reset definition of res as shown in edit.

It is perfect now. Thank you!

Also with the use of Frame -> {{True, True}, {False, True}} in p1 and Frame -> {{True, True}, {True, False}} in p2, we get the plot with a common x-axis.
